# Sqlite, ArrayList and Spinner

Tags: android, kotlin

I am adding the data in sqlite to arraylist and then adding it to spinner but i need to close and open the application to make it appear in spinner

```
mainList.clear()
val DataBase = openOrCreateDatabase("Park", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null)
val cursor = DataBase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM BT_Main", null)
val mainNameIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex("MainName")
while (cursor.moveToNext())
{
    mainList.add(cursor.getString(mainNameIndex))
}
cursor.close()
```

**Spinner Adapter**

```
val mainAdapter = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, mainList)
layoutBnd.loginSprMain.adapter = mainAdapter
val mainAdapterStyle = ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.user_sprsytyle, mainList)
mainAdapterStyle.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.user_sprsytyle)
layoutBnd.loginSprMain.adapter = mainAdapterStyle
```

Comment: Are you calling the spinner adapter code after the write of data to DB and the read of data from db to `mainList`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.